# Permanent Caching with C# IMemoryCache on TEST IIS Machine does not work

Tags: c#, reactjs, iis, caching, .net-5

I have a Windows Server 2019 with an IIS server for .NET5 application with React frontend uses IMemoryCache to store data from DB. It loads over 5GB for 6 minutes into Memory (over 500 000 000 rows).

When I run app from VS Professional, Cache works perfectly for more than 6-12 hours (or more), but after I deploy & run the web app on IIS, Cache works less than 30 minutes

```
//Simplify class using
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
//Simplify class var.
private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
//Simplify class constructor
public GroupLoader(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _memoryCache = memoryCache;
}

// Store to CACHE
var cacheExpiryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
{
      AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6),
      Priority = CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove,
      SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(180)
};

_memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, data, cacheExpiryOptions);
```

I do not know where is the problem, but is it possible to use IMemoryCache for permanent cached data? Missing some IIS set ?

Comment: Is the server restarting? The code above isn't going to remove values from cache, so it is possible that the process is restarting, or soemthing is causing new values to be inserted and your old values to be removed, leading to cache misses. In addition, how do you know that it only works for less than 30 minutes?

Comment: I try it over 6 times, and everything with same result, I do not restart server, and also do not change anything, only try web app with browser, server has 24 GB only for my app.
I log times when app loads again to cache

Comment: Maybe it causes IIS setting for web app Pool - **Idle TimeOut**, but I think than IMemoryCache is shared cache

Comment: IIS worker process can be recycled/restarted in many cases, so you shouldn't expect anything in memory (`IMemoryCache`) to be "permanent". Please switch to out of process caching mechanism instead.

Comment: It is not suggest to use memorycache for permanent cach data. It is easy to lose data when server down.You can use other In-memory database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible settings seems to be this, in any case, it is necessary to clean (recycle) the memory every day, so this is a temporary solution. I hope it also helps someone, as a permanent solution is the use of InMemory Redis.

> IIS -> ApplicationPools -> (Select your pool) -> Advanced Settings

[image]